# How to change attribute error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am overriding the RequiredAttribute and in my IsValid method I need the ability to change the ErrorMessage property.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Some custom required message about the Foo property")]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

and inside the IsValid method:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Some custom required message";
        ...
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant how do I change the ErrorMessage in my code, as I am overriding the IsValid method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679202.aspx

Comment: @user517406, inside the IsValid method you could set the `ErrorMessage` property. I have updated my answer to illustrate that.